# C# Windows Program Miscalculated in Billion Value

Tags: c#

I have source code like this in button click event:

```
int a = 0; decimal b = 0;
a = 1000;
b = 3000 + (a - 2) * 1000;
txtSummary.Text = b.ToString("N0");
```

I test some value in a variable like this :

- 1,000 result  1,001,000
- 10,000 result  10,001,000
- 100,000 result  100,001,000
- 1,000,000 result  1,000,001,000
- 10,000,000 result  1,410,066,408 (**WRONG**). The correct is  10,000,001,000

What wrong with my code ? Program create in .NET Framework 3.5. Visual Studio 2015. Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Change `1000` to `1000m`.

Comment: It is the exact same kind of problem as double c = 1/2;  The operands are *int* so you get integer division, the result is always 0.  Same here, all operands are int so you get integer multiplication.  And it exceeded int.MaxValue, it overflowed.  Just making one of the operands decimal is enough, 1000m gets it done.  Do favor Project > Properties > Build > Advanced button > "Check for arithmetic overflow".  Now you get a nice exception instead of garbage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do an integer multiplication, and after that convert it to a decimal (i.e. you're dealing with an integer overflow).

Ratio: `3000 + (a - 2) * 1000;` -> 3000 is an int, `a` is an int, 2 is an int, 1000 is an int. Therefore, `a-2` will give an int, `(a - 2) * 1000` also results in an int, and (guess...) `3000 + (a - 2) * 1000` is an int. Assignment finally casts to a decimal. Not what you expected, right? :-)

Solution: Cast the components (`a` will suffice) to a decimal *first*, then do the calculation.

Answer (score 4):

As the max `int` [value is 2,147,483,647](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), the value overflows and "wraps" around. It does even so several times.

potential solutions :

- Use `decimal` for your variable `a` instead of `int`.
- Cast at least one of the number you use to `decimal` by appending a `m` in the operation that overflows or by casting.

Example :

```
b = 3000 + (a - 2m) * 1000;
```

or

```
b = 3000 + (a - 2) * 1000m;
```

or

```
b = 3000 + ((decimal) a - 2) * 1000;
```